# In angular I an not able to refresh the data of my table

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my code:

[image]

My page is not refreshing its data after delete or any other operations it is not giving me list of user in the data. I tried but I am not able to get any easy solution and I am a beginner so I am not able to understand the code in the web so please give me an detailed explanation and code snip.

Comment: Please post your code here, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of refreshing the table after any data manipulation operation is to creating an individual select queried method and call this perticularly on the event of delete, update or insert.
In case of Angular we can use the `this.ngOnInit();` after the manipulation operation performed.

If this won't work.
Use `@ViewChild` in your component class to reference the template property and invoke the  `renderRows()`  function whenever there is a modification in the table data.

> Code Below

```
@ViewChild('myTable') myTable: MatTable;
    editDataMethod(){
        /* data handling logic */
        this.myTable.renderRows();
```

> Reference: [Angular refresh table after delete record, using material table and rest api](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/angular-refresh-table-after-delete-record-using-material-table-and-rest-api)